# True of False? Assume that $f$ is a differentiable function on (0,1) with $|f'(x)|\leq4$ for every $x\in(0,1)$. Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is a differentiable function on (0,1) with $|f'(x)|\leq4$ for every $x\in(0,1)$. If {$x_n$} is a Cauchy sequence in (0,1) then {$f(x_n)$} is also Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

By asumption, $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $4$ (prove that). Use it with a suitable choice of $\varepsilon$ to prove your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\{x_{k} \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, there exists $N$ such that $|x_{m} - x_{n} | < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ for all $n, m > N$. Now, note that by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c_{n, m} \in (x_{n}, x_{m}) \subset (0,1)$ such that $|f(x_{m}) - f(x_{n})| = |f'(c_{n,m})||x_{m} - x_{n}| \leq 4|x_{m} - x_{n}| < \epsilon$ for all $n, m > N$. This shows that $\{f(x_{n}) \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.